# LibreOffice menu bar bug (5.2.1.2)?

Tags: libreoffice, menu

Has anyone encountered this problem?

LibreOffice 5.2.1.2 (Writer) shows a **blank menu field** under the Menu bar just above the toolbar. Can I fix this?

Using Ubuntu UNity 16.04.1. LTS

[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: It's Numix both icons and theme.

Comment: Can you try disabling the theme (and icons, and then rebooting) and see if the problem still occurs? I can try to install Numix myself in a few hours and see if I have the same problem.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, with `numix-gtk-theme 2.1.2-0ubuntu1` - sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: Could be related to a release-upgrade, but I am not sure. Try to downgrade LO to 5.1.4.2 which is in repositories to check if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, rather a workaround, suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830539/libreoffice-blank-menu-bar-after-launch-until-reload-libreoffice-gui), click on the little black cross on the right, and then you are redirected to the start menu, but then, opening or creating a doc won't have the blank toolbar anymore.